# mysql max function usage

Tags: mysql, function, max

the table `videos` has the folowing feels
`id`,`average`,`name`
how can i write the query, to select the name of video, which have the max `average`!!!
i can do that vith two queries, by selecting the max(`avege`) from the table, and then find out the name, where ihe `average` equal to max!!! but i want to do that in one query!!!
help me please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `ORDER BY` with a `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT id, average, name FROM videos ORDER BY average DESC LIMIT 1
```

`ORDER BY average DESC` orders the rows in order of descending `average` (i.e. the first row will have an `average` equal to `MAX(average)`). `LIMIT 1` causes only the first row to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a group by for this, you just want to select the highest average!

```
SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY average DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT id,name,MAX(average) FROM videos;`

All fields you choose to `SELECT` will be returned. Getting more data back is just a case of `SELECT`ing more fields.